# How can I use the YouTube API inside an AMD module?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, amd

The YouTube API expects certain functions to be attached to the window object. Which seems simple enough:

```
requirejs(function() {
  console.log('i am being loaded')
  window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    console.log('ready')
  }
});
```

In this case, 'i am being loaded' is logged, but 'ready' is never shown.

I can see the correct function appears on window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady from the browser console.

However a script tag works:

```
<script>
  window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
   console.log('ready from script tag')
  }
</script>
```

Logs correctly.

What am I doing wrong? How can I use the YouTube API inside an AMD module?